# Making small edits to my posts all the time bumps them to top; I need to stop, right?

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette, bump

I have a habit of repeatedly editing my own posts.  I like to aim for perfection.  Partly since the site encourages answering my own questions and treating that like a blog post.

I notice this bumps my posts, and I feel guilty :(.

So I need to try easing off on editing simply for optimal word choice.  Maybe avoid trivial edits unless there was also a substantial change in the last 5 minutes.   Am I right in thinking that would be preferable?

Comment: That post is not an exact duplicate and is based on rules that have changed slightly since then, but the basic sentiment is: avoid trivial edits.